# mysql select multiple values from array match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I have an array lets say: Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 7 [2] => 8 )

I want to SELECT from a table (users) all phone numbers where userID matches one from the array (if there is a phone number listed).

I want to do this without selecting all of the users from the database and only those that match that of the array and with actual phone numbers, should I do this in a loop?

Typically when I am doing an UPDATE, I do them within a foreach loop.  Like so:

```
foreach($userArr as $user) {
            $pid = $user;
            if(!$statement->execute()) {
                    throw new Exception($statement->error, $statement->errno);
            }
    }
$statement->close();
```

Can we do SELECT like that as well?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to select all these users, just do the follow:

```
$idList = implode(',', $yourArray);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN($idList)";
// execute this $sql query
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    <?php

    $array = array(9, 7, 8);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = ";

    $condition = implode(' OR id = ', $array);

    $query .= $condition;

    echo $query;
?>
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 9 OR id = 7 OR id = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

1. Build a string to express the userid seperated by comma. - Loop will be needed. **i.e** id1, id2, id3
2. Build the query string to search for them.

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE id IN (id1, id2, id3)
```